# Duplicate variables (null copy) in loop?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've never seen this before.. I have the following code, a simple nested loop assigning an object from one ArrayList to an object of another.

But, inside the inner loop, the object has some (not all) duplicate variables with null values?!? What am I doing wrong?!?

The first image shows the local variable "member", a reference to an object inside the ArrayList "members". This is the object with duplicate variables with null values.

The second image show the other object "offer", looking like one would expect.

Code below. Help?

[image: Duplicate variables with null value]
[image: As it should be]

```
public static void setMembersForOffers(ArrayList<WPMemberPost> members, ArrayList<WPOfferPost> offers)
{
    int memberCount = members.size();
    int offerCount = offers.size();

    for (int i=0; i<offerCount; i++)
    {
        WPOfferPost offer = offers.get(i);

        if (offer.memberIdentifier != null)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<memberCount; j++)
            {
                WPMemberPost member = members.get(j);
                String id = member.identifier; // NULL?!? (Expected "436")

                if (offer.memberIdentifier.equalsIgnoreCase(id))
                {
                    offer.member = member;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Is there really a problem or are you just confused to why you see duplicates in the debugger? 2. Can you add info for how your WPOfferPost/WPMemberPost classes are structured? 3. Nybakta ekologiska kanelbullar, det låter gott ;) (For those who did not understand, this was written in Swedish and is a reference to one of the pictures)

Comment: Is it causing any errors in your program? If not, I would say it's an Eclipse/Debugger issue and ignore it
**edit:** @SimonAndréForsberg was faster ;-)

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear (added a comment to the affected line in the code). The problem is that the wrong value is used! Check out the line "NULL?!? (Expected "436")

Comment: show us your classes. i guess you declared members twice

Comment: I cannot see what is surprising you: the second loop is iterating on members list, and some of them have the identifier as null. The previous if ensures the offer.memberIdentifier is not null, but nothing in that method ensures member.identifier is not null

Comment: I promise you, I haven't. The class containing the method above only contains two other static methods, that's it.

Comment: @PabloLozano Check out the first screen shot, there are duplicate variables inside the SAME OBJECT, that's not normal.

Comment: Nope, I had defined the variable in both the superclass and subclass. Stupid mistake (see example below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course two variables with the same name can exist in an inheritance hierarchy

Try this code and make a breakpoint in the main method at `System.out.println(subclass);`.
In the debugger you will see that the variable exists two times, because it is defined in `Base` and `Subclass`.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Subclass subclass = new Subclass();
        subclass.someString = "test";
        System.out.println(subclass);
    }

    private static class Base {

        public String someString;

    }

    private static class Subclass extends Base {

        public String someString;

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are of course correct! The class "WPMemberPost" wasn't always a subclass, hence my mistake of the duplicate variable definitions... Thank you!